# In Python, can I create a for loop to create multiple linear regressions for different variables

Tags: python, for-loop, error-handling, scipy, regression

I have a dataframe containing npi values, periods (in weeks), and product IDs. for each product ID I want to create a linear regression of period on the x-axis and npi on the y axis then append the results from the linear regression to a new dataframe. How can I do this?

my code was:

```
for prod in product_array:
    data_aggr_period_prod_loop =data_aggr_period_prod.loc[data_aggr_period_prod['product']==prod]
    x = data_aggr_period_prod_loop['period']
    y = data_aggr_period_prod_loop['npi']
    result = stats.linregress(x,y)
    slope = result.slope
    intercept = result.intercept
    y_hat = slope*x + intercept
    appended_data = appended_data.append(result, ignore_index = True)
```

But it comes out with this error:

> TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types, and
> the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types
> according to the casting rule ''safe''

is my code correct for what I want to do and how do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we could create a regression "loop".

The error "ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types " usually referred to the **data type you inputted** (which is string usually). Make sure the input variable is in **numpy variable type**.

p.s. it is better to save model perfermance in each iteration, by comparing it later to optimize!

Comment: How would i change my x and y to a numpy variable, currently my x is an object and y is a float

Comment: @BismahGhafoor what do you mean by object. 
Maybe you should try using the regression without the loop first , 1st -> loop.
Then we can debug through the data type(source) problem or the iteration problem

Comment: hi, so I have managed to do this which got rid of that error: for prod in product_array:
    data_aggr_period_prod_loop =data_aggr_period_prod.loc[data_aggr_period_prod['product']==prod]
    x = np.array([date_map[ix] for ix in df['period']])
    y = data_aggr_period_prod_loop['npi']
    result = stats.linregress(x,y)
    slope = result.slope
    intercept = result.intercept
    y_hat = slope*x + intercept
    appended_data = appended_data.append(y_hat, ignore_index = True)

Comment: this then gets me this error: ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 26 and the array at index 1 has size 25

Comment: This is data problem, please check the first row and second row and see if there is any difference